# How do i tell if an output an integer or not in C

Tags: c

i Have this homework about a superhero  triangle, from what i got if the Area an integer data, then it's a superhero triangle, if it's not then it's not a superhero triangle.

The problem is, how do i determine if the output an integer or not

Thank you

Note : English is not my main language, sorry for the lack of vocabulary to describe it

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: "how do i determine if the output an integer or not" what does that mean? An output is something you control.

Comment: @bitmask probably she has a function that returns a float/double and wants to know if the value returned is an integer number. Hard to tell without an example though.

Comment: A hero triangle seems to be a triangle with integer sides and integer area. It's a superhero triangle if its perimeter is the same as its area. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIjeCKPHbso

Comment: Do you mean __input__?

Comment: @GerardoZinno Ah, I figured output as in "program output" as in `printf`. But this guesswork isn't helping OP.

Comment: I guess the question is that given the three side lengths, determine if it's a superhero triangle, which means computing the area and testing to see if it's an integer, and then checking if it's the same as the perimeter.

Answer (score 1):

Well I believe your calculation is all with doubles, because you are not sure of the result maybe an int maybe double. but you just need to know if it's really a double or an int, in your case 2.0 is an int of course, so I made this simple example for you

```
#include <iostream>

int isFloat(double n) {
  return n - int(n) > 0;
}

int main(void) {
  double x = 2.1;
  if(isFloat(x)) {
    std::cout << "it's a float";
  }else {
    std::cout << "it's an int";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**output**
`it's a float`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are just trying to check if a number is an integer (not necessarily the type but just that it has no decimal values... ex: 5.00 is an integer)

You could use the math.h standard library like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double output_value = 1.27;
    if(fmod(output_value, 1.00) != 0)
        //This is not an integer
    else
        //This is an integer
}
```

Clearly, if a number is not evenly divisible by 1, it is not an integer.
This seems like the simplest solution to me.